We need to delete the Ldap address book on Outlook through script
# Define the LDAP registry path

$ldapRegPath = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles"



Get-ChildItem -Path "Registry::$ldapRegPath" -Recurse|select name, property|foreach{

  $path = $_.name -replace 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER', 'HKCU:'  

  $_.property|foreach{

    $name = $_

    $result = Get-ItemPropertyValue $path -name $name|where-object {$_ -eq 'SecureMail DirResponder'}

    if ($result -ne $Null){    

      Remove-Item -Path $path -Force

      Write-Output "$path deleted successfully."

    }

  }

}

We can delete the Ldap address book by using above script but when we reopen the outlook we are getting address book promt , now we don't want see the that papup
